# How to add auto incremental sequence of numbers if a specific number is already being used

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, increment, auto-increment, hardcoded

If I have a hard coded value of '04200001000000' and wanted to auto increment the last number. I cannot find anything online regarding this function. I am using SQL server 2014.

Example:

```
0420000100000001
0420000100000002
0420000100000003
0420000100000004
0420000100000005
0420000100000006
0420000100000007
0420000100000008
0420000100000009
0420000100000010
```

Comment: What happens when you get 10 rows?

Comment: When there are 10 rows the 15th Char will be a "1".  If there are 100 rows then the 14th char will be a 1, 15th 0, 16th 0 @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information, but depending on the type of the column this may work:

`ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN columnName IDENTITY (04200001000001, 1);`

Comment: So this EmpNo is a specific column in a table that I have created. Right now the column is set as: TabEmpNo = '04200001000001' which is a hardcoded value. This value will be the same for all Employees except for the last digits depending on how many rows. So if there are 5 rows: 04200001000001,04200001000002,04200001000003,04200001000004,04200001000005

Comment: Is there a way I can add a case statement somehow to auto increment these values?

Comment: What's the type of the column? If it's a number of some type the above should work. Once run, just leave `EmpNo` blank when adding new rows and the database will automatically fill in the next number.

Comment: The identity seed must be an integer, so it can't begin with zero i.e. 042

Comment: @Nathan are you sure SQL Server interprets numbers with a leading zero as an octal (or a non number)?

Comment: @AlvinThompson No, that's not what I am saying. It will do an implicit conversion to an integer, thereby removing the leading zero. Therefore this is not an approach that can be used to generate the required strings of digits.

Comment: @Nathan, obviously, padding a number with leading zeros is not an issue that should be solved by the number's internal representation in the DB--that's an issue of formatting when converting the number to text for display. Similarly, if you store a `date` in a DB, it isn't stored as "28 June 2017". That is how you choose to display it. You could also choose to display it as "6/28/17".

Comment: @Nathan the only way what you're arguing would be an issue is if there's a possibility that `420000100000001` could be an ID as well as `0420000100000001`. The OP makes it clear that's not the case.

Comment: @Nathan you **could** also use the `LPAD` function to add the zeros in Oracle when retrieving the ID, but that would be terrible for many, many reasons.

Comment: @AlvinThompson the OP explicitly says the value is "hardcoded" as "042.." i.e. the leading zero is integral to the value being stored. Obviously it would be much easier to store an integer value and simply append a leading zero when displaying it in a UI, however I don't believe that is what is being asked here.

Comment: @Nathan what you’re saying doesn’t make sense. if as you say the ID can’t be an integer value because it has a leading 0, then OP could not use auto increment, which is explicitly what he’s asking for.

Comment: @AlvinThompson - well it makes sense to me, I don't know another way of explaining this that you would understand. The answer provided above does not produce the results being asked for in the question, feel free to test it out if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE INT @CurrentPos = (SELECT MAX(CAST(TabEmpNo AS INT))
    FROM Table);

SET @CurrentPos = SELECT IIF(@CurrentPos IS NULL, 4200001000000, @CurrentPos);

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Col1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS RN
    FROM TABLE
)
INSERT INTO TABLE
(
    Col1,
    TabEmpNo
)
SELECT Col1,
    CONCAT('0', CAST(RN + @CurrentPos AS VARCHAR(13))) AS TabEmpNo
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your employee "number" is actually a character data type (since it includes a leading zero) you can potentially use a SEQUENCE.

e.g.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.EmpNumbers
AS BIGINT
START WITH 4200001000000
INCREMENT BY 1
MIN VALUE 4200001000000
MAX VALUE 9999999999999
CACHE 10
;
```

You can then use this to generate a new employee number as new employees are added e.g.

```
SELECT 
     EmpName
   , '0' + CAST((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.EmpNumbers) AS CHAR(13)) AS NewEmpNumber 
FROM NewEmployees
```